Cannot decrypt Linux Mint files on log in
I have a dual boot laptop with Windows and Linux mint. In the Linux Mint partition I encrypted the file storage and this has been working fine for 4+ years, it decrypts on log in. Yesterday some software may have filled my Linux partition and today when I try to log in to Linux I can not get past the log in screen and receive the error:
ecryptfs_write_metadata_to_contents: Error attempting to write header information to lower file: rc = [-20]
ecryptfs_write_metadata: Error writing metadata out to lower file: rc = [-20]
Error writing headers: rc = [-20]

and it just keeps going back to the log in screen.
I booted Linux in recovery mode and used the root shell. I tried running the following commands but received the following errors:
# ecryptfs-mount-private
ERROR: Encrypted private directory is not setup properly

# ecryptfs-recover-private
INFO: Searching for encrypted private directories (this might take a while)...
INFO: Found [/home/.ecryptfs/foo/.Private].
Try to recover this directory? [Y/n]: Y
INFO: Found your wrapper-passphrase
Do you know your LOGIN passphrase? [Y/n]: Y
INFO: ENTER your LOGIN passphrase...
Passphrase:
Inserted auth tok with sig [79***2e] into the user session keyring
mount: /tmp/ecryptfs.Q1***1M: mount(2) system call failed: No such file or directory.
ERROR: Failed to mount private data at [/tmp/ecryptfs.Q1***1M].

I'm thinking maybe the Linux partition is too full to decrypt the files on log in but it may also be that the encryption is corrupt? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
